# Converting a byte array to a vector drawable

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm pulling out vector drawables from a server in bytes arrays. I need to parse them in an exploitable resources to show in views. How can i do that ?

Comment: use [SVGImageView](https://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/doc/index.html?com/caverock/androidsvg/SVGImageView.html) (or [SVG](https://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/doc/index.html?com/caverock/androidsvg/SVGImageView.html) when `SVGImageView` cannot be used)

Answer (score 0):

You can use library that can render SVG. For example [androidsvg](https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg) using getFromInputStream() method for reading svg from byte array

```
   /**
* Read and parse an SVG from the given {@code InputStream}.
* 
* @param is the input stream from which to read the file.
* @return an SVG instance on which you can call one of the render methods.
* @throws SVGParseException if there is an error parsing the document.
*/
   @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
   public static SVG  getFromInputStream(InputStream is) throws SVGParseException
   {
      SVGParser  parser = new SVGParser();
      return parser.parse(is, enableInternalEntities);
   }
```